# Как на jquery поставить checked всем checkbox что бы флажок ставился по одному и желательно рандомно

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Есть кучка чекбоксов, у каждого есть свой id. Хочу чтобы при загрузке документа загорелись те, которые я хочу. Но что бы не одновременно загорелись, а через допустим 200 миллисекунд, и в рандомном порядке.

Не могу додуматься как это сделать. Сколько не пробовал, либо загораются все сразу, либо вообще не загораются.

[image: Чекбоксы]

```
 $('#sass').prop('checked',true);
```

Вот так писал. Как задать им очередь не знаю

Comment: "те которые я хочу" и "рандомным образом"? Это как?

Comment: Я хочу что бы загорелись допустим только html5 sass jquery
я пишу $('#html,#sass,#jquery').prop('checked',true); 
но что бы не одновременно загорелись, а через допустим 200 миллисекунд, и в рандомном порядке. sass html jquery
jquery sass html, при каждой загрузке страницы, рандомным образом загорались но только эти 3.
Рандом не столь важно, сделать бы хотя бы что бы просто была задержка эта.

Comment: если ответ помог решить вашу проблемы, вы можете отметить его принятым, нажав на галочку рядом с ним

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Выбираем все желаемые элементы.
2. Превращаем набор в массив.
3. Перемешиваем используя [алгоритм Фишера-Йетса](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8,_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0).
4. Для каждого элемента массива создаём задержку для изменения чекбокса.

```js
function shuffle(a) {
  for (var m=a.length; m; ) {
    var i = Math.random() * m-- | 0;
    var t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[m];
    a[m] = t;
  }

  return a;
}

$(function () {
  var DELAY = 500;

  var els = shuffle($("#a,#c,#g,#i,#j,#k,#l,#o,#p,#s,#u,#v,#x").toArray());
  
  for (var q=0; q<els.length; ++q) {
    setTimeout(function (el) { 
      $(el).prop('checked', true)
    }, DELAY * q, els[q]);
  }
});
```

```css
label { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input type=checkbox id=a>a</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=b>b</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=c>c</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=d>d</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=e>e</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=f>f</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=g>g</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=h>h</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=i>i</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=j>j</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=k>k</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=l>l</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=m>m</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=n>n</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=o>o</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=p>p</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=q>q</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=r>r</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=s>s</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=t>t</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=u>u</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=v>v</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=w>w</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=x>x</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=y>y</label>
<label><input type=checkbox id=z>z</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

Для последовательного выбора чекбоксов используйте `setTimeout()`, предварительно поместив необходимые `id` в массив и "перемешав" его.

**Важно**, чтобы перечисление `id` чекбоксов было без пробелов и отделялось запятой, например, `'html,sass,jquery'`:

```js
function check(checkboxes) {
  var arr = checkboxes.split(','); // разбиваем строку на массив
  shuffle(arr); // перемешиваем массив
  arr.forEach(function(id, index) { // перебираем получившийся массив
    setTimeout(function() { // задаем задержку
      $('#' + id).prop('checked', true); // отмечаем чекбокс
    }, index * 1000); // задержка равная индексу значения, умноженному на 1000 миллисекунд (0*200, 1*200 и т.д.)
  });

}

function shuffle(a) { // функция перемешивания массива
  for (let i = a.length; i; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    [a[i - 1], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i - 1]];
  }
}

check('html,sass,jquery');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="html" /> html <br />
<input type="checkbox" id="css" /> css<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="javascript" /> javascript<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="sass" /> sass<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="gulp" /> gulp<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="css3" /> css3<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="jquery" /> jquery<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="bootstrap" /> bootstrap<br />
```

Функция перемешивания массива позаимствована из [ответа на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6274381/8255361).

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот как-то так получилось :

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  var cbs = $('#5, #6, #7, #8, #9, #10');
  var newCbs = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
    newCbs.push({
      cb: cbs[i],
      num: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
    });
  }

  newCbs = newCbs.sort(compare);
  xz(newCbs);
});

function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.num > b.num) return -1;
  if (a.num < b.num) return 1;
  return 0;
}

function xz(arr) {
  if (arr.length == 0) return;
  var current = arr[0].cb;
  arr.shift();
  setTimeout(function() {
      $(current).prop('checked', true);
      xz(arr);
    },
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000) + 1);
};
```

```css
.that {
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="1" class="that" />
<input type="checkbox" id="2" class="that" />
<input type="checkbox" id="3" class="that" />
<input type="checkbox" id="4" class="that" />
<input type="checkbox" id="5" class="that" />
<input type="checkbox" id="6" class="that" />
<input type="checkbox" id="7" class="that" />
<input type="checkbox" id="8" class="that" />
<input type="checkbox" id="9" class="that" />
<input type="checkbox" id="10" class="that" />
<input type="checkbox" id="11" class="that" />
<input type="checkbox" id="12" class="that" />
<input type="checkbox" id="13" class="that" />
<input type="checkbox" id="14" class="that" />
<input type="checkbox" id="15" class="that" />
```

Comment: А где же у вас выборка по определенным id?

Comment: про нее я забыл, но сделать выборку по ид не сильно сложно